# Confused on how to overload the == operator

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

My assignment is having us overload the `==`, `<`, and `>` operators. I understand that operator overloading essentially overrides the code of an operator. I have found a way to overload the `+` and `-` operators. My problem appears when I try to overload the `==` operator. Maybe I am going about this wrong, but I am trying to make a function to return a string saying that they are equal or not.

```
Temperature operator == (Temperature const &temp1, Temperature const &temp2)
{
    int holder;
    if(temp1 == temp2)
    {
        holder = 1;
    }
    return holder;
}
```

I also tried to return 1 so that I could make a if statement in the main function to check if their equal or not.

```
Temperature operator == (Temperature const &temp1, Temperature const &temp2)
{
    string holder;
    if(temp1 == temp2)
    {
        holder = "temp1 is equal to temp2";
    }
    return holder;
}
```

I know that there's not much difference between the attempts but I'm struggling to find ways to go about it.

Comment: What is the exact problem you encounter when you try to use `==`?

Comment: Pop quiz: what does "`if(temp1 == temp2)`" does in the shown code? It's a trick question. Of course it compares these two objects. Now, ask yourself how it does that, and maybe you'll figure out what the obvious problem is here.

Comment: In the first example, `holder` is not initialized.  So what will be returned if `temp1` was not equal to `temp2`?  Whatever junk value `holder` happened to be would have been returned.  Please initialize your variables.  Also, if you claimed you overloaded other operators, my suspicion is that those overloads also contain errors and oversights, given what you're showing us here.

Comment: It's good practice, when overloading operators, to return a type consistent with how the native operators work. Conditional operators should return bool, arithmetic operators should return the types of their operands produce. There are exceptions, but when a person reads code later, they will expect operators to behave consistent with how native operators would be expected to work

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4):

Your operator is returning the wrong type.
It should look like this:

```
bool operator == (Temperature const &temp1, Temperature const &temp2)
```

return `true` if the two compare equal, `false` otherwise.

Comment: That's one problem. Another is the `if (temp1 == temp2)` test.

Comment: Yes, put some trivial example as to how he sould do something like `return temp1.value == temp2.value`

Answer (score 2):

Your code got three problems. First, you're trying to compare two objects by calling compare operator within compare operator for those two objects (ie. calling itself). Second, you're returning an object value instead of `bool`. ***An you're returning uninitialized value when comparison failed.***

It's obvious from your code, that `Temperature` is context-convertible from `int`, i.e., it's some integral type,  in this case overload causes problems. You have to have an unambiguous overload.

In general, free-standing `operator==` for `MyClass` may look something like this:

```
bool operator == (MyClass const &a1, MyClass const &a2)
{
    return  (a1.value1 == a2.value1) && (a1.value2 == a2.value2); 
}
```

It should be a friend function or have access to members of class, of course.

The point of overloading operators is to define them for particular type(s) of parameters. They are functions, just like  any other overloaded function and must be distinctive from other instances of that operator. They may introduce a new behavior (example: << and >> operators of `<iostream>`), or just provide implied behavior. Exclusions are new\delete and type conversion operators.

Comment: Note that the parentheses in the `return` statement aren't needed. Many people (i.e., me) balk at redundant parentheses.